# Best approach to run multiple mysql queries in one statement in php

Tags: php, mysql

What is the best approach to run multiple mysql queries in one statement in PHP?

Currently using preg_split to split queries using semicolon (;) and running multiple queries. But as I understand this approach is vulnerable for injection.

Is it possible in mysqli ? and How ?

Thanks.

Comment: do you have any sample on how you do things? If so please provide.

Comment: What are you trying to achieve with 2 queries in a single statment. Can we get any sample to your idea behind to do so

Comment: for example, one query to insert data in tableA and one query to update data in tableB. I have been using 3-4 queries in single statement with semicolon as a separator but not sure whether it is secured and proper way of doing it. Observed one thing, when user enters (; DROP table tablename;) in input field, the table gets deleted. I want to avoid this.

Answer (score 1):

To run multiple queries with [mysqli](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php), you'd use

- [`mysqli_multi_query`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.multi-query.php) - Executes one or multiple queries which are concatenated by a semicolon.

Because the query is a string in this case (instead of a statement), you cannot use parameter binding, so you need to make sure the [queries are properly escaped](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.real-escape-string.php).

Also see this page dedicated to [Multiple Statements with mysqli](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.multiple-statement.php):

> The API functions `mysqli_query()` and `mysqli_real_query()` do not set a connection flag necessary for activating multi queries in the server. An extra API call is used for multiple statements to reduce the likeliness of accidental SQL injection attacks. An attacker may try to add statements such as `; DROP DATABASE mysql` or `; SELECT SLEEP(999)`. If the attacker succeeds in adding SQL to the statement string but `mysqli_multi_query` is not used, the server will not execute the second, injected and malicious SQL statement.

And further down that same page:

> Use of the multiple statement with prepared statements is not supported.

So yes, **you need to make sure any user provided parts of the multiquery are not malicious**, in which case it's probably simpler to just use single queries.